# Datos repetidos en formato PDF, no respeta condicional IF

Tags: php

acudo a ustedes por que estoy atorado desde hace varios días con un código y por mas que trato de buscarle solución no me da la cabeza ya, espero me puedan apoyar con esto por favor.

```html
<a href="ver_estudios_pacientes.php?numero_factura=<?php echo $numero_factura;?>&fecha=<?php echo $fecha;?>&idcliente=<?php echo $id_cliente;?>&idmedico=<?php echo $id_medico;?>&sexo=<?php echo $sexo;?>" target="_blank" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver análisis del paciente' ><span class="icofont-file-pdf icofont-2x"></span> Ver análisis</a>
```

**Y luego tengo el archivo PHP el cual mando a llamar todos los formatos e imprimo solo los formatos que contengan datos del paciente.**

```php
session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
        header("location: ../../login.php");
        exit;
    }

    include("config/db.php");
    include("config/conexion.php");

  require_once __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

    $num_fac = $_GET['numero_factura'];
    $id_cliente  = $_GET["idcliente"];
    $fecha           = $_GET["fecha"];
    $id_medico   = $_GET["idmedico"];
    $sexo              = $_GET["sexo"];

/////////// GRUPO RH /////////////////////////////////

$sql="SELECT c.nombre_cliente,m.nombre_medico,q.* from clientes c,resul_grupo_rh q, medicos m where q.numero_factura='".$num_fac."' and q.id_cliente='".$id_cliente."' and c.id_cliente=q.id_cliente and q.fecha='". $fecha."' and m.id_medico='".$id_medico."'";
$resul=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rw_resul_grh=mysqli_num_rows($resul);

if ($rw_resul_grh == 0){
}else {
    include("ver_estudios_pacientes/grupo_rh.php");
}
```

Cuando mando a llamar estos dos archivos php grupo_rh.php y factor_reumatoide.php se me imprime todoas las condicionales IF y no me los respeta como es y es raro ya que en en1° boton de editar resultado puedo imprimir el formato que es sin que este se repita.

Dejo el archivo php que no me respeta las condicionales IF

```
    <?php
    
    $sql="SELECT c.nombre_cliente,m.nombre_medico,q.* from clientes c,resul_grupo_rh q, medicos m where q.numero_factura='".$num_fac."' and q.id_cliente='".$id_cliente."' and c.id_cliente=q.id_cliente and q.fecha='". $fecha."' and m.id_medico='".$id_medico."'";
    $resul=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $rw_resul=mysqli_fetch_array($resul);
    
    $grupo = isset($rw_resul["grupo"]) ? $rw_resul["grupo"] : '';
    $factor = isset($rw_resul["factor"]) ? $rw_resul["factor"] : '';
    $vih = isset($rw_resul["vih"]) ? $rw_resul["vih"] : '';
    $vdrl = isset($rw_resul["vdrl"]) ? $rw_resul["vdrl"] : '';
    
    //$grupo = $rw_resul["grupo"];
    //$factor = $rw_resul["factor"];
    //$vih = $rw_resul["vih"];
    //$vdrl = $rw_resul["vdrl"];
    
    if($grupo || $factor || $vih || $vdrl){
    
        //VIH solo
        if(empty($grupo) and empty($factor) and isset($vih) and empty($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>V.I.H</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.I.H: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vih.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
          <div style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 70%;">
              <span style="font-size:15px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Antonio Martinez García</font></span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 76%;">
              <span style="font-size:13px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Químico Clínico</font></span>
            </div>
          </div>';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    
        //VDRL solo
        if(empty($grupo) and empty($factor) and empty($vih) and isset($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>V.D.R.L</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

    
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.D.R.L: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vdrl.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
          <div style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 70%;">
              <span style="font-size:15px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Antonio Martinez García</font></span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 76%;">
              <span style="font-size:13px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Químico Clínico</font></span>
            </div>
          </div>';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    
        //VIH y VDRL solos
        if(empty($grupo) and empty($factor) and isset($vih) and isset($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>V.I.H - V.D.R.L</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.I.H: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vih.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
    
            
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.D.R.L: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vdrl.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
          <div style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 70%;">
              <span style="font-size:15px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Antonio Martinez García</font></span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 76%;">
              <span style="font-size:13px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Químico Clínico</font></span>
            </div>
          </div>';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    
        //Grupo y Factor solos
        if(isset($grupo) and isset($factor) and empty($vih) and empty($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>GRUPO RH</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Grupo Sanguineo: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$grupo.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Factor RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$factor.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
          <div style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 70%;">
              <span style="font-size:15px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Antonio Martinez García</font></span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 76%;">
              <span style="font-size:13px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Químico Clínico</font></span>
            </div>
          </div>';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    
        //Grupo Sanguineo - Factor RH y VIH solos
        if(isset($grupo) and isset($factor) and isset($vih) and empty($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>Grupo RH - V.I.H</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
 
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Grupo RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$grupo.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Factor RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$factor.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.I.H: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vih.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
          <div style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 70%;">
              <span style="font-size:15px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Antonio Martinez García</font></span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 76%;">
              <span style="font-size:13px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Químico Clínico</font></span>
            </div>
          </div>';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    
        //Grupo Sanguineo - Factor RH y VDRL solos
        if(isset($grupo) and isset($factor) and empty($vih) and isset($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>Grupo RH - V.D.R.L</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Grupo RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$grupo.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Factor RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$factor.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.D.R.L: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vdrl.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
          <div style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 70%;">
              <span style="font-size:15px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Antonio Martinez García</font></span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#fff; margin: 0 0 0 76%;">
              <span style="font-size:13px;" ><B><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Químico Clínico</font></span>
            </div>
          </div>';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    
        //Los 4 valores a la vez (Grupo Sanguineo - Factor RH - V.I.H - V.D.R.L)
        if(isset($grupo) and isset($factor) and isset($vih) and isset($vdrl)){
            $cadena.='
         <style>
         th, td {
             border: 0;
             width: 100px;
         }
         .nombre{
             width: 300px;
         }
         .fecha{
             width: 100px;
         }
         .datos{
             width: 50px;
         }
         .resultado{
             width: 100px;
         }
         </style>
    
         <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td style="width:35%;" ALIGN="LEFT" valign="top">
             <img src="./img/logo-photo.png" width="220" height="230" ><br>
           </td>
           <td style="width:50%; color: #444444;" align="right">
             <img width="100%" height="230" src="./img/cuadro_lab.png" alt="Logo"><br>
           </td>
         </tr></table><BR><BR>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="nombre"><B>Paciente: </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_cliente"]).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="fecha"><B>Fecha: </B>'.$dia.' - '.$m.' - '.$an.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"><BR><B>Doctor(a): </B>'.strtoupper($rw_resul["nombre_medico"]).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><BR><B>DETERMINACION</B></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
            <br><BR><BR>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;" ><BR><B>Grupo RH - V.I.H - V.D.R.L</B></p><BR>
    
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                     <td style="font-size:18px;" colspan="2"></td>
                     <td align="center"><b><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial" style="font-size:18px;">Resultado</font></b></td>
                     <td class="espacio"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Grupo RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$grupo.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">Factor RH: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$factor.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.I.H: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vih.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
                    <td class="datos" align="left" style="font-size:20px;"  colspan="2">V.D.R.L: </td>
                    <td class="resultado" align="center" style="font-size:19px; font-weight:bold;"><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">'.$vdrl.'</font></td>
                    <td class="espacio"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        ';
    
         $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['','format' =>'Letter-P','mode'=>'utf-8','margin_header'=>15,'margin_footer'=>20,'orientation' =>'P','tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
         $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('./img/logo1.png');
         $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
         $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.1;
         $mpdf->writeHTML($cadena);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No es  que no te respete, lo que  sucede que a las variables o le asignas el valor del campo de la tabla o los pones en  '' y el isset para ambos casos retorna TRUE. A las finales todos tus `if` son  TRUE.

Comment: Creo que el isset da true si la variable existe, aunque esta valga false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que no te respete, lo que sucede que a las variables o le asignas el valor del campo de la tabla o los pones en '' y el isset para ambos casos retorna TRUE. A las finales todos tus if son TRUE. Debes asignar NULL en lugar  de

```
$grupo = isset($rw_resul["grupo"]) ? $rw_resul["grupo"] : NULL;
$factor = isset($rw_resul["factor"]) ? $rw_resul["factor"] : NULL;
$vih = isset($rw_resul["vih"]) ? $rw_resul["vih"] : NULL;
$vdrl = isset($rw_resul["vdrl"]) ? $rw_resul["vdrl"] : NULL;
```

Tus if deberian cambiar los empty por  `!isset`.

```
 if(!isset($grupo) and !isset($factor) and !isset($vih) and isset($vdrl))
```

Comment: Hola mi amigo ya lo complemente en otro formato de condicionales que tenia y me sirvio de mucha ayuda mi hermano, te super agradezco por tu tiempo y  te mando un gran saludo mi hermano.

Answer (score 1):

Particularmente yo prefiero usar `empty` para verificar los valores posteados.

Para simplificar el código, podrías **asignar de una vez por todas cada variable con un ternario** y luego **usar esa variable en todo**.

Veamos la definición de las variables:

```
$grupo = !empty($rw_resul["grupo"]) ? $rw_resul["grupo"] : NULL;
$factor = !empty($rw_resul["factor"]) ? $rw_resul["factor"] : NULL;
$vih = !empty($rw_resul["vih"]) ? $rw_resul["vih"] : NULL;
$vdrl = !empty($rw_resul["vdrl"]) ? $rw_resul["vdrl"] : NULL;
```

Ya las variables recogieron los valores ... o son nulas en caso de no existir o no tener datos. Ahora USA SOLAMENTE LAS VARIABLES PARA TODO.

Los `if` quedarían así:

```
if($grupo || $factor || $vih || $vdrl){

    //VIH solo
    if(!$grupo && !$factor && !$vdr1 && $vih){
        //... Código ...
    }


    //VDRL solo
    if(!$grupo && !$factor && !$vih && $vdrl){
        //... Código ...
    }

    //VIH y VDRL solos
    if(!$grupo && !$factor && $vih && $vdrl){
        //... Código ...
    }

    //Grupo y Factor solos
    if($grupo && $factor && !$vih && !$vdrl){
        //... Código ...
    }

    //Grupo Sanguineo - Factor RH y VIH solos
    if($grupo && $factor && $vih && !$vdrl){
        //... Código ...
    }

    //Grupo Sanguineo - Factor RH y VDRL solos
    if($grupo && $factor && !$vih && !vdrl){
        //... Código ...
    }

    //Los 4 valores a la vez (Grupo Sanguineo - Factor RH - V.I.H - V.D.R.L)
    if($grupo && $factor && $vih && $vdrl){
        //... Código ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola mi amigo ya implemente como lo tienes tu y de verdad que te super agradezco ya me sale y si respeta las condicionales a como debe de ser, te mando un gran saludo mi hermano.

Comment: @OscarGerardoGonzalezHernand me alegro de que te haya servido. En los `if` puedes comparar directamente las variables sin necesidad de volver a usar `isset` o `empty`, lo cual sería redundancia en el código. Saludos.